# Allow a user to move Jquery tabs around ( Re-order them by dragging )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Cant seem to find a clear example of how to do this..

So, 
I have a bunch of Jquery tabs. Some get created and deleted on the fly by the page.
How can I enable them to be "Re-ordered" Ie: A user clicks and drags one to the beginning of the list..?

A bit like how you can re-order google chrome tabs.. But for Jquery UI tabs?

Any ideas much appreciated.

Thanks
Graham

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The obvious answer for me would be - jquery SORTABLE added to your tabs elements.
Refer to jquery docs - http://jqueryui.com/sortable/.

But if tabs are saved in interface for user(after login the order is maintaned) you would have to set up database access and save the positions of tabs into it.

Comment: Oh My God.. That simple.. How on earth did I miss this!!